# how to implement interoperable web service that returns generated bit map?

Tags: web-services, wcf, rest, wsdl

I have only implemented WCF Web Services generated from WSDL with WSCF Blue. They are synchronized WSs that have simple type elements in messages to both ways.

Now I need to do something different. Again request contains simple type elements but the response should be the bitmap. Now i'm wondering how to do this. I still use .NET/VS 2013 to implement it, but should I use WSDL or not. I want this WS to be as interoperable as possible. To be called both from desktop applications, Web applications and other Web Services.

Does it make sense to make it REST with only GET supported? The service does not store anything, it just generates the bitmap and returns it.

Comment: If you create your service using WCF, then you can have it both ways - it's just one service contract with two bindings.

Comment: can you please point me to some additional info about this?

Comment: You can't find additional information about WCF? What I wrote is a fundamental feature of WCF.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to return a bitmap, depending on size and the bitmap generation time.

For small bitmap and fast operation, you may simply return a byte array, for example., through byte array, you may have:

```
[OperationContract]
byte[] GetBitmap(string id);
```

for large bitmap, you may consider streaming, please refer to [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks! my question was actually quite a bit larger, but why not always stream it? like [OperationContract]
        Stream GetMapPicture(string id);

Comment: For small bitmap, probably not much different if there's no error during the data transfer, and could be more subject to your preference. For large data, streaming surely has some obvious advantages, but also be subject to some restrictions as documented in the msdn link. Nevertheless, I myself prefer streaming, especially when many parts of the call stacks on the service side also do  streaming. Please make sure you read the reference carefully and adjust config accordingly.